# My check for whether a graph is a Binary Tree always returns false

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures

I have this question that is medium level and couldn't even think on how to solve this problem, my solution could be overkill as I have no idea on how to traverse a bunch of numbers in an array to check whether it is a binary tree or not. The program always returns false no matter what

If you have a better answer to the question that would be perfect

> Have the function `TreeConstructor(strArr)` take the array of strings stored in `strArr`, which will contain pairs of integers in the following format (i1, i2) where i1 represents a child a node in a tree and the second integer i2 signifies that it is the parent of i1. For example if `strArr` is `["(1,2)", "(2,4)", "(7,2)"]`
>
> ```
>     4 
>    /
>   2
>  / \
> 1   7
> ```
>
> which you can see forms a proper binary tree. Your program should, in this case, return the string true because a valid binary tree can be formed. If a proper binary cannot be formed with the integer pairs, then return the string false. All of the integers within the tree will be unique, which means there can only be one node in the tree with the given integer value
>
> **Examples**
>
> ```
> input: ["(1,2)", "(2,4)", "(5,7)", "(7,2)", "(9,5)"]
> output: true
>
>
> input ["(1,2)", "(1,3)"]
> output: false
> ```

I came out with an attempt, but it always returns false. Most likely my code is overkill.

```
class Node {
  // The constructor
  constructor(value) {
    this.value = value;
    this.left = null;
    this.right = null;
  }
  // Basic insert node
  insert(value) {
    let currentNode = this;
    while (true) {
      if (value < currentNode.value) {
        if (currentNode.left === null) {
          currentNode.left = new Node(value);
          break;
        } else {
          currentNode = currentNode.left;
        }
      } else {
        if (currentNode.right === null) {
          currentNode.right = new Node(value);
          break;
        } else {
          currentNode = currentNode.right;
        }
      }
    }
    return currentNode
  }
    // check if BST is valid or not
    isValidBST(node, min = null, max = null) {
    if (!node) return true;
    if (max !== null && node.value >= max) {
      return false;
    }
    if (min !== null && node.value <= min) {
      return false;
    }
    const leftSide = this.isValidBST(node.left, min, node.value);
    const rightSide = this.isValidBST(node.right, node.value, max);
    return leftSide && rightSide;
  }
}

// Convert the strings to a number 
function convertListToNumber(str, i) {
  return str[i].split('(').join('').split(')').join('').split(',').join('')
}
```

This is the main function

```
function TreeConstructorTwo(strArr) { 
  // code goes here  
  startValueFromList = convertListToNumber(strArr, 0)
  // Parent Node here
  startParentNode = startValueFromList[1];
  // Child Node here
  startChildNode = startValueFromList[0];
  // Add parent Node and childNode
  node = new Node(startParentNode);
  node.insert(startChildNode);
  // Loop through the entire array
  for (i = 1; i < strArr.length; i++) {
    myListValue = convertListToNumber(strArr, i);
    console.log(myListValue.length)
    // Loop the "12" in the string and convert it to a number
    for (j = 0; j < myListValue.length; j++) {
       node.insert(myListValue[j])
    }
    parentNode = Number(myListValue[0])
  }
  // Check if the BST is valid or not
  return node.isValidBST(node)
}

// keep this function call here 
console.log(TreeConstructorTwo(["(1,2)", "(2,4)", "(5,7)", "(7,2)", "(9,5)"]));
```

Comment: Read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for tips on debugging your code.

Comment: Do you even need to build the tree in order to validate it? Focus on the properties a BST must exhibit (number of children, etc). The input doesn't specify what's left and what's right, so as long as you have the proper number you could arrange them validly. The tree doesnt have to be complete or balanced.

Comment: You've got 1) a question, 2) some examples, 3) some code. What you're missing is an algorithm.

Comment: @PartyLich do you have suggestions of how to validate? can't think of any, hence why I did left and right probably to validate the tree

Comment: @user3386109 I'm not smart, hence why I asked for guidance :)

Comment: My point was the you've skipped the most important part of the process. You should design an algorithm, and present that algorithm in the question. Then we can discuss the algorithm. Currently, I would have to reverse-engineer the code to try to guess what your algorithm is.

Comment: What constitutes a "proper" binary tree?  I mean, I can think of a few things that would make it obviously not a binary tree:  e.g.:  a node that has more than one parent; more than one node that has no parent; a cycle of any length; or a node that has 3 or more children;  But then there are some cases that are not so clear.  What if a node has only one child?  Is that still okay?  What if there are no nodes at all?  Is that "proper"?  is that "valid"?  These terms need definitions. (Props to @trincot who made a decent list of valid binary tree criteria - but what is "proper")

Comment: Yes, that is all proper by definition of BT. Its not ambigious at all. "Proper" and "valid" already have plain English definitions that we can use. Its not "proper", aka "invalid", if it has properties that make it NOT a binary tree.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to have misunderstood the assignment. The function should return true when the represented tree is a binary tree, not necessarily a binary *search* tree.

Your code is creating a tree from the first element and then takes any next node to insert it into that tree keeping with the binary search property, without taking into account that the pair from the input demands that the first is a direct child of the second. (Your variable `parentNode` is not used for anything)

Instead, you should just look at the child-parent relationships that are given in the input as representing *edges*, and use that information to build the graph. Finally you should verify that that graph represents a [binary tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree). Think about what are the distinctive characteristics of a binary tree and how to verify them.

Hint 1:

> No node should have two parents

Hint 2:

> No node should have 3 children

Hint 3:

> All upward paths should end in the same node (the root)

The spoiler solution below does not return true/false, but a string that indicates whether the tree is "ok", or why it is not. This is more useful for debugging and still easy to convert to a boolean.

```js
// This function returns the reason why it considers the input
// not a binary tree. "ok" otherwise.
function isBinaryTree(edgesStr) {
    const childToParent = new Map(edgesStr.map(edge => edge.match(/\d+/g)));
    // No node should have 2 parents
    if (childToParent.size < edgesStr.length) return "node with two parents";
    // No node should have 3 children
    const degree = {};
    for (const [child, parent] of childToParent) {
         if ((++degree[parent] || (degree[parent] = 1)) > 2) return "node with three children";
    }
    // All upward paths lead to the same root (no cycles)
    const nodes = {};
    let current = 0;
    let countRoots = 0;
    for (let node of childToParent.keys()) {
        current++;
        while (node && !nodes[node]) {
            nodes[node] = current;
            node = childToParent.get(node);
        }
        if (!node && countRoots++) return "disconnected";
        if (node && nodes[node] == current) return "cycle";
    }
    return "ok";
}

const tests = [
    ["(2,1)", "(3,1)", "(4,2)", "(5,2)", "(6,3)", "(7,3)"],
    ["(1,2)", "(3,2)", "(2,12)", "(5,2)"],
    ["(2,1)", "(3,1)", "(5,4)", "(5,2)"],
    ["(2,1)", "(4,3)"],
    ["(1,2)", "(3,4)", "(4,5)", "(5,3)"],
];

for (const test of tests) {
    console.log(isBinaryTree(test));
}
```

NB: I would name the function with an initial lowercase letter as it is the common practice to reserve initial capital letters for class names.

Comment: Is no nodes (and consequently no edges) still a valid binary tree?  Some might say yes.  Your criteria of "there is exactly one node that has no parent" might need to be tweaked a little.

Comment: Correct: rephrased.

Comment: I wished I could break the problem like you @trincot

Answer (score 2):

Recently I've did the solution for this task, check my solution below:

```js
const isBinaryTree = (array) => {
  const getChildrenNode = (node) => node.slice(1, 2);
  const childrenNodes = array.map(x => getChildrenNode(x));
  const isChildrenNodesIsUnique = (array) => array.length === new Set(array).size;
  
  return isChildrenNodesIsUnique(childrenNodes);
};


console.log(isBinaryTree(["(1,2)", "(2,4)", "(5,7)", "(7,2)", "(9,5)"]));
console.log(isBinaryTree(["(1,2)", "(1,3)"]));
```

Comment: it's doesn't work for ```["(1,2)", "(3,2)", "(2,12)", "(5,2)"]```

Comment: Doesn't work for `["(1,2)", "(3,4)"]` either; nor for `["(12,2)", "(1,2)"]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
In C# this is a code

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

 

public class Program
{
    public static bool TreeConstructor(string[] strArr)
    {
        var arr = new List<int>();
        var counts = new Dictionary<int, int>();

 

        foreach (var pair in strArr)
        {
            var matches = 
             System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(pair,@"\d+");
            arr.Add(int.Parse(matches[0].Value));
            arr.Add(int.Parse(matches[1].Value));
        }

 

        foreach (var x in arr)
        {
            if (!counts.ContainsKey(x))
                counts[x] = 1;
            else
                counts[x]++;
        }

 

        foreach (var count in counts.Values)
        {
            if (count >= 4)
                return false;
        }

 

        return true;
    }

 

    public static void Main()
    {
        // Test cases
         Console.WriteLine(TreeConstructor(new string[] { "(1,2)", "(2,4)", " 
         (5,7)", "(7,2)", "(9,5)" })); // Output: True
        Console.WriteLine(TreeConstructor(new string[] { "(1,2)", "(3,2)", " 
        (2,12)", "(5,2)" })); // Output: False
    }
}
```

Comment: The question is about javascript, not C#. And code only answer don't help much.

Comment: This is not required

Answer (score -1):

I did this by collecting the parent ids in an array and checking if any parent id is exists more than twice. Not sure though it will

["(1,2)", "(3,2)", "(2,12)", "(5,2)"]

since 2 came 3 times at the right of the pair its a false (a root or leaf node cannot have more than 2 childs)

Answer (score -1):

```js
const isBinaryTree = (array) => {

  // find the parent child
  const parentChildFreq = (value) => {

    const charFreqency = {};
    for (let index = 0; index < value.length; index++) {
      if (charFreqency[value[index]]) {
        // if parent have more the 2 children then this is not binary-tree
        if (charFreqency[value[index]] >= 2) {
          return false;
        }
        charFreqency[value[index]] += 1;
      } else charFreqency[value[index]] = 1;
    }
    return true;
  };

  const isChildrenNodesIsUnique = (array) =>
    array.length === new Set(array).size;

  const childrenNodes = array.map((node) => node[1]);

  let parentsNodes = array.map((node) => node[3]);
  parentsNodes = Array.from(parentsNodes, Number);
  

  return isChildrenNodesIsUnique(childrenNodes) && parentChildFreq(parentsNodes)
    ? " \n Binary-tree"
    : "not-binary-tree";
};

console.log(isBinaryTree(["(1,2)", "(2,4)", "(5,7)", "(7,2)", "(9,5)"]));
//console.log(isBinaryTree(["(1,2)", "(3,2)", "(2,12)", "(5,2)"]));
```

Comment: Note that this incorrectly reports this as a binary tree: ["(1,2)", "(3,4)", "(4,5)", "(5,3)"]. It's a disconnected graph with a cycle, definitely not a binary tree.   Also, code-only answers aren't very helpful.

Answer (score -1):

I had it at a coding interview, could not make it on time but later I did this. It seems to be working but it is as good as my tests are. It seems that this two conditions are enough:
-A node can have less than 3 child.
-Every node has a parent but one.

```
  function ArrayChallenge(strArr) {
  //Make a num array
  const numArray = strArr.map((str) => {
    var mySubString = str.substring(str.indexOf("(") + 1, str.lastIndexOf(")"));
    return mySubString.split(",").map(Number);
  });

  //Get parent nodes
  const parents = numArray.map((arr) => {
    return arr[1];
  });

  //Get children nodes
  const children = numArray.map((arr) => {
    return arr[0];
  });

  //Conditions

  //a parent can't have 3 children
  const threeChildrenCondition = findRepeated(parents) < 3 ? true : false;
  const allHaveParentsButOneCondition = allHaveParentsButOne();

  //every node has a parent except for one
  function allHaveParentsButOne() {
    var parentOfAll = parents.filter(function (num) {
      return children.indexOf(num) == -1;
    });

    //Will remove duplicate numbers (parent appearing two times)
    let unique = [...new Set(parentOfAll)];

    const result = unique.length == 1 ? true : false;

    return result;
  }

  //Returns how many times a number is repeated in an array
  function findRepeated(array) {
    let repeatedNumbers = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      for (let j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++) {
        if (array[i] === array[j]) {
          repeatedNumbers.push(array[i]);
        }
      }
    }
    const length = repeatedNumbers.length;
    return length;
  }

  const result = threeChildrenCondition && allHaveParentsButOneCondition;

  return result;
}

//CHALLENGES

//Must be false
const f0 = ["(1,2)", "(3,2)", "(2,12)", "(5,2)"];
const f1 = ["(1,4)", "(3,2)", "(2,12)", "(5,2)"];
const f2 = ["(1,7)", "(3,7)", "(2,7)"];
const f3 = ["(10,20)", "(20,50)", "(20,8)", "(8,4)"];

console.log(ArrayChallenge(f0));
console.log(ArrayChallenge(f1));
console.log(ArrayChallenge(f2));
console.log(ArrayChallenge(f3));

//Must be true
const t0 = ["(1,2)", "(2,4)", "(5,7)", "(7,2)", "(9,5)"];
const t1 = ["(2,3)", "(1,2)", "(4,9)", "(9,3)", "(12,9)", "(6,4)"];
const t2 = ["(1,2)", "(2,4)", "(7,4)"];
const t3 = ["(5,6)", "(6,3)", "(2,3)", "(12,5)"];
const t4 = ["(10,20)", "(20,50)"];

console.log(ArrayChallenge(t0));
console.log(ArrayChallenge(t1));
console.log(ArrayChallenge(t2));
console.log(ArrayChallenge(t3));
console.log(ArrayChallenge(t4));
```

Comment: Note that this incorrectly reports this as a binary tree: `["(1,2)", "(3,4)", "(4,5)", "(5,3)"]`.  It's a disconnected graph with a cycle, definitely not a binary tree.

Answer (score -1):

```
 public static bool TreeConstructor(string[] strArr)
    {
        var treeList = new List<int[]>();
        foreach (var node in strArr)
        {
            treeList.Add(Array.ConvertAll(node.Replace("(", "").Replace(")", "").Split(","), s => int.Parse(s)));
        }

        bool isChildNotUnique = treeList.GroupBy(s => s[0]).Any(g => g.Count() > 1);
        bool isMoreThanTwoChild = treeList.GroupBy(s => s[1]).Any(g => g.Count() > 2);
        int[] rootNode = null;
        if (isChildNotUnique || isMoreThanTwoChild)
            return false;

        foreach (var node in treeList)
        {
            var childNodes = treeList.Where(s => node[1] == s[1]);

            bool leftChild = childNodes.Any(s => s[0] < node[1]);
            bool rightChild = childNodes.Any(s => s[0] > node[1]);

            if (childNodes.Count() > 1 && (!rightChild || !rightChild))
            {
                return false;
            }
            else if (!leftChild && !rightChild)
                return false;

            bool isNotRootNode = treeList.Any(s => s[0] == node[1]);
            if (!isNotRootNode)
                if (rootNode != null && rootNode[1] != node[1])
                    return false;
                else
                    rootNode = node;

        }

        return true;

    }
```

Comment: First, code-only answers aren't very helpful.  Second, this was tagged `JavaScript`.  `Java` is an entirely different language.